# SSRS_How to set textbox in page header which change its value by group in tablix

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to set text box in page header which value changes by group in the tablix.

I tried placing a hidden textbox and using parameter, but they don't work.

Setting pagename property of group is not a perfect solution for me this time, because I need to place more than one text box that changes its value by group.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by using switch statement?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but the thing is you get error message unless you specify which value from tablix to show in the textbox. e.g. =First(Fields!item.value, "dataset name") => you get error without "First", but value doesn't change with it.